# Frequent short system hangs

Tags: 18.04, kernel, freeze, amd-graphics, 20.04

Every 25 seconds or so my computer (Originally 18.04, updated to 20,04 to try and fix) will completely freeze up for about 2-5 seconds. Even in the middle of typing up this message it would do it. The only thing that doesn't freeze is the cursor, but sometimes the freezes are once every ten seconds. A 2-5 second freeze a few times a minute is crippling. I set bios back to original settings since this workstation was shipped to me. It's an AMD 570 GPU and when I attempted to install AMDGPU I would just get black screen (looks like I wasn't alone there). When I run `dmesg -T` every single system hang lines up perfectly with this message

```
[Thu Apr 30 12:52:10 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 12:52:10 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 12:55:09 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 12:55:09 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 13:00:06 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 13:00:06 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 13:00:11 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 13:00:11 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[Thu Apr 30 13:00:42 2020] [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
```

I can still wiggle my cursor but that's it. May also be notable, but when I shut down through the UI shutdown menu the system will completely freeze until I force restart. Just typing this message was insufferable given how many times I had to sit here and wait to be able to type again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.